# SQL Limit Average

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a database with 169461 records. Within one field is begin_milepost that numerically counts up from 0 at 0.01 intervals. I want to change the interval from 0.01 to 0.1 by making a new column that averages ten records at a time to create one record, and having it do this all the way down. I'm using access 2013.

Example would be 0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08,0.09,0.1 being turned into 0.055 and repeating on the next ten records.

Comment: sample data would help.

Comment: 0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04,0.05,0.06 and so on.

Comment: @BenZeddicus Add the data sample to your question, not to the comments. Include desired output *and* any attempted solutions

Answer (score 0):

See if this gives you what you are looking for: 
`SELECT (([Marker]-0.01)*100)\10 AS MarkerGroup, Sum([Marker])/Count([Marker]) AS AvgMarker
FROM tblMarkers
GROUP BY (([Marker]-0.01)*100)\10;`